# What is required for advanced lungs to filter dangerous chemicals (so to speak, to carry out the detoxification process) and then use oxygen?

Tags: hard-science

What is required for advanced lungs to filter dangerous chemicals (so to speak, to carry out the detoxification process) and then use oxygen? (It is advisable to take into account the above record, since the concept of using a second pair of lungs already exists; you need a different solution).

The main question: what needs to be changed (added) in the lungs of a person so that he is not poisoned by toxic air. For example, mine air may contain gases such as nitrogen, methane, carbon monoxide (carbon monoxide is very toxic, easily combines with hemoglobin in the blood, preventing oxygen from entering the bloodstream and causing oxygen starvation of the body.), sulfur dioxide, hydrogen sulfide, nitrogen oxides, methane, hydrogen, heavy hydrocarbons, radon, ammonia and other harmful gases, as well as water vapor and dust. This link shows the poisonous gases that need to be dealt with: https://vk.com/wall544212004_7.

(In my opinion, it would be possible to modify the lungs so that between the blood vessels and the alveoli there was some kind of structure that filters the air from chemically hazardous substances.)

To reiterate: **What needs to be changed in the lungs (or somewhere else) of a person so that he can breathe poisonous air**?

Filled with sulphurous gases (Oxide sulfur (IV)), for example, in principle, the better this person will carry the gases poisonous to us in the atmosphere, the better.

Comment: What do you classify as "dangerous chemicals"? Does it include inert gasses or powders, for example? And for the benefit of those who can't read it, perhaps you should summarise the content of your link.

Comment: in this video, the doses of human-dangerous poisons are shown in the most detail ( https://youtu.be/flv0ql218-A )

Comment: Hazardous chemicals mean gases by inhalation of which a person will die. The most important example is the increase in CO2. After all, a concentration of more than 5% (50,000 ppm) becomes fatal for a person.

Comment: Potentially yes - at the expense of breathing efficiency.

Comment: What have lungs to do with eating puffer fish?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Is this abut the *inhalation* of poison (via lungs) or the *consumption* of poison (via digestive system)? It seems to start with the former and than abruptly shifts to the latter. Vote to close.

Comment: CO2 is ***not*** a poisonous gas. Our bodies actually use pCO2 to control the respiratory rate. If you scrub out the CO2, you'll end up with a severe case of respiratory alkalosis. Bad joujou that. That said, welcome to WB.SE!  Please take the [tour] and review the [help].  They're designed as a guide to help you write good queries and responses. This particular question needs a lot of work. Especially the bits about the pufferfish and mushrooms. Those are respiratory non sequuntur.

Comment: Agree on close vote: this is two interesting questions, so they need splitting up into one question for breathing, and one for eating.

Comment: Sorry, I just went here last night, so I could have done something wrong.
My "main" question: What needs to be changed in the lungs (or somewhere else) of a person so that he can breathe poisonous air? Filled with sulphurous gases (Oxide sulfur (IV)), for example, in principle, the better this person will carry the gases poisonous to us in the atmosphere, the better

The rest is another question. I probably should ask it separately, but if anyone has ideas for a solution to this problem

Comment: Dewi Morgan. that's right, that's what I wanted to say

Comment: @FrenchThompson if you inhale a load of fine yet inert dust you can die. A hypoxic gas mix containing a harmless inert gas and a small amount of oxygen will also kill you without being actually toxic. Those were the sort of corner cases I was interesed in.

Comment: @FrenchThompson also, your post-alveoli filtering idea will fail when faced with something like chlorine gas which will damage the lungs enough to prevent gas exchange withouut necessarily getting into the bloodstream at all. Your link listing the gasses you're interested in remains unreadable to many users, so make sure you have _all_ the salient details in your question(s).

Comment: This link shows the poisonous gases that need to be dealt with: https://vk.com/wall544212004_7.                         Then what do you think will solve this problem? (what needs to be added or changed in human lungs)

Comment: A lot of "air" is dangerous just becasue it doesn't have enough oxygen.

Answer (score 1):

As your article notes, a number of the chemicals are toxic to the skin and eyes itself, so lungs wouldn't be enough.

[A gas mask would be needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_mask) Some sort of tweak to the face and mouth to prevent toxic gases from reaching the lungs along with a filter to prevent toxic gases from getting inside.

You'd also need to tweak the blood [to carry more oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_substitute). This would allow them to work in low or no oxygen conditions for longer.

I imagine someone with rubbery skin, resistant to chemicals, and a large and powerful nose to smell chemicals. When they enter a toxic place they can put a second eyelid over their eyes they can see through and seal off their mouth and nose, with a filter to slowly draw oxygen in. Energetic work would drain their oxygen faster than they could draw it in, but they could rest between exertions and use machines. Their blood and liver and such would be tweaked to handle small amount of poisons that leaked through, processing them faster, but the main barrier would be the sealed off face.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a sort of multi-stage lung could do the trick.

If one of the requirements is that it is one set of lungs (not multiple), we might consider a lung that has filtering layers for different chemicals.

For example, you mentioned Carbon Monoxide.  Taking a queue from our cars, the lungs could contain a layer of ultra small diameter bones with a thin coating of platinum and palladium, which would convert it to Carbon Dioxide.  Below that may be a layer of symbiotic algae which could convert that into Oxygen.

There's a few real-world problems with that approach, but it might be enough for fiction.

Comment: tell us more! ( as much detail as possible), this option is very curious and potentially solves problems

Comment: That is, you are proposing the creation of several microscopic layers of carbon fibers coated with a layer of platinum and paladium ( fermentation of these rare chemical elements will probably be taken from food), which through the interaction of the above chemical elements will change the carbon monoxide into carbon dioxide.
But what about the following toxic gases: like nitrogen, methane, carbon monoxide, sulfur dioxide, hydrogen sulfide, nitrogen oxides, methane, hydrogen, heavy hydrocarbons, radon, ammonia and other harmful gases, as well as water vapor and dust That need to be improved or

Comment: added to the human lungs or circulatory system so that people can breathe normally (or simply not be poisoned by them)? as mentioned above Your idea of post-alveolus filtration will fail when faced with something like chlorine gas, which will damage the lungs enough to prevent gas exchange without having to enter the bloodstream at all.

Comment: tell us more! ( as much detail as possible), this option is very curious and potentially solves problems!

Comment: What you say is true, @FrenchThompson.  That particular reaction will only work for Carbon Monoxide.  For more broad spectrum, you would need more layers like certain gas masks.  A layer of activated charcoal would grab quite a bit, but for something like chlorine you then need another layer of sodium thiosulfate.  A 100% all purpose filter has yet to be invented, so but varied layers might work.

Comment: well. But what poisons can we survive against? (And the question is, will oxygen still pass or is there no longer with this filter?

Comment: Can you write as much as possible, which “layers” (highly specialized layers of this biological filter in the lungs) will be needed to deal with poisons?

If the platinum layer and palladium solve the problem with carbon monoxide.
A layer of sodium thiosulfate solves the problem of chlorine poisoning.
What more can be done?

Comment: @FrenchThompson, I'm afraid we have reached the limit of my knowledge of chemistry :) .  I based that above information on WW1 gas masks (for surviving Chlorine gas) and the catalytic converter in automobiles.  But beyond that, you'd probably have to ask a chemist.

Comment: You could not find out (from your previous sources or learn the answer to this topic from familiar chemists, perhaps on this forum)?. I have not been here for a long time, but asking this question directly will be considered a repetition.